# When should the jungler leave the kills to the lanemate?

Tags: league-of-legends

When ganking my lanes in the laning phase of the game, when should I leave the kill to the lanemate (assuming the kill is safe and the enemy won't get away)?

There are some junglers, like Alistar, with whom I always leave the kills to them (since Ali Ganks live from the CC and not the dmg), but what about more DPS like Junlgers like Nocturne for example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first rule for that is always: It's better anyone gets the kill than noone gets the kill, so don't risk someone escaping with 5hp just because you thought the other guy had his gap closer ready when he hadn't.

The second rule would be: Know the item builds of your teammates.

Who gets the kills depends on which champion is more item dependant.
As an example if you are a jungle bruiser like Lee Sin you are usually more item dependant than most tanks in the top lane, so you can make better use of the extra gold.
If you are a jungle tank like Nautilus and the top lane is a bruiser, let him take the kill if the opportunity arises, the extra gold will help him win the lane.
As an exception, if the tank top laner requires an early item for higher efficiency, for example Tear or Manamune on Yorick, leave the kills to them until they have completed that item.

For mid and bot, always try to leave them the kills if there is no chance for the opponent to escape.

Answer (score 1):

You really shouldn't look after who gets the kill, cause usually the benefit the lane has from the enemy beein dead (exp advantage, cs advantage) is way bigger than the 300gold anyways.

If you play a supportive type of jungler (maokai, Alistar, Nautilus; basicly all the dudes you get double gp10 on) you should only take 1- 2kills (to get the gp10 items) and after that leave the kills to your mates, since you can do your job (CC, be disruptive) without items/gold as well.

If you play more of an aggressive/Bruiser type of jungler (noc, Shyv, Sin) you could take more kills, but you shouldn't even care about who gets the kills if you play these champs really, cause it deosn't matter. With these junglers, you scale just as well as your laners, so just KILL something, wheter you get the kill or the assist really doesn't matter.

Comment: It may be that it's only a quite little difference of Gold between the Kill and the asssist, but I still think it matters. Regarding high competitive play (tho I may be not playing at such an high elo) there is already a difference of 10 CS quite huge, which is also "just" 200 Gold.

Comment: It is mainly the teamgold that matters. As you said, 10 cs is a quite huge diffrence, and if your jungler ganks for you, and you kill the enemy, you will get those 10 cs, and the enemy wont. Results in you gettin 200 gold over him anyways, even if the jungler took the kill. Getting killed in a gank is not even a concern to most players, cause thats 300gold, basicly NOTHING compared to how much you loose if you get zoned What really matters is how much XP the laner who died looses, how much cs he gets behind, and if his tower gets pushed/objectives get forced. Who gets the kill is insignificant

Answer (score 1):

To answer the "when" part of the question, it depends on the champion you are using as a jungler. Some are very powerful at level 2(shaco, sin, shyv) whereas some champs need to be level 4 before they can output a viable amount of damage(noc, mundo).

I believe that when ganking bot with a damage type jungler, try to let the AD carry get the kills, but elsewhere, it doesnt matter as much, since a fed jungler is going to have devastating ganks and do tons of damage.

If you are jungling with a utility champ (naut, ali, maokai) then its better for the lane to get the kill, since you arent there to do massive damage from great items, but rather be a pain in the but to the other team with your excessive amounts of CC. So just get some GP5 items, get a little bit of health, and CC the crap out of the enemy team in team fights later on.